# How to style toolkit:ListPicker full mode in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am having problem styling the full mode of listpicker. I want it should fully cover the page but I see a margin from the left and up in full mode.

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Header="SELECT TRANSLATION" x:Name="lspTranslationLang"
SelectedItem="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionChanged="lspTranslationLang_SelectionChanged">
<toolkit:ListPicker.HeaderTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <StackPanel>
     <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" Text="Select Translation"></TextBlock>
   </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
  </toolkit:ListPicker.HeaderTemplate>
  <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock FontSize="30" Text="{Binding Language}" />
   </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
  </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
  <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    Grid Margin="0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="30" Height="30" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding ImagePath}" ></Image>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Padding="10,0,10,0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Language}" FontSize="30"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Padding="10,0,10,0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="30"/>

    <Line X1="0" X2="480" Y1="0" Y2="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="LightGray" />
  </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
  </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

How I can change the style for full mode of listpicker?

Comment: Are you getting margin of 10px frpm left and top ??

Comment: It's 12px from left and 24px from top, but I want to change it to zero and at the same color the background.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial for customizing list picker from geekchamp.

[Customizing list picker](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/customizing-listpicker-for-wp7-part1)

Change the data template of the full mode property. And set the margins using expression blend. It is a good editor in customizing.

Comment: That's only for WP7 not WP8

Answer (score 0):

You must probably add the following property

```
ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly"
```

Comment: I set that property but still I see margin there, I want to remove that margin from top and left.

Comment: It seems like the margin comes by default with the listpicker